# How to POST to a modelViewSet that has a GenericForeignKey?

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-contenttypes

I have a model that uses the django content type framework

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    object_id = models.UUIDField()
    contentObject = GenericForeignKey()
```

then I use the modelViewSet and the serializer

```
class FooViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = FooSerializer
    queryset = Foo.objects.all()

class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = ('__all__')
```

how can I create data using POST to the viewSet?
I arbitrary tried POST the object id from another model to `content_type`, `object_id`, and `content_object` then I got the error "Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received str."

I already look in http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#generic-relationships or look in stack overflow but can't find any about how to POST the data, maybe my search wasn't thorough enough, I'm sorry. Thanks for checking out my question

**UPDATE**

I tried to override the create method in serializer:
I try to get the ContentType object from `get_for_model` method, but it return AttributeError: 'AnotherModelX' object has no attribute 'replace'

```
def create(self, validated_data):
        content_type =  validated_data.get("object_id")
        taggedObject = AnotherObject1.objects.get(id=content_type) if AnotherObject1.objects.filter(id=content_type).count() > 0 else None
        taggedObject = AnotherObject2.objects.get(id=content_type) if AnotherObject2.objects.filter(id=content_type).count() > 0 and taggedObject == None else None

        if taggedObject is not None:
            contentType = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(taggedObject)
            if contentType is not None:
                validated_data["content_type"] = contentType
                validated_data["object_id"] = taggedObject
        return super(FooSerializer, self).create(validated_data)

class Meta:
    model = Foo
    fields = ('__all__')
    extra_kwargs = {
        'content_type': {'required': False},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my last update was close to the solution, 
it should be assigning an id in the `validated_data["object_id]` then it works. Here are the POST json data to `Foo`:

```
{
  "object_id": <<another_model_uuid>>
}
```

Be sure to get all the possible model so `taggedObject` contains the instance of a model.

It is now solved then, thank you!

Bellow is the correct `create` method in serializer

```
def create(self, validated_data):
        content_type =  validated_data.get("object_id")
        taggedObject = AnotherObject1.objects.get(id=content_type) if AnotherObject1.objects.filter(id=content_type).count() > 0 else None
        taggedObject = AnotherObject2.objects.get(id=content_type) if AnotherObject2.objects.filter(id=content_type).count() > 0 and taggedObject == None else None

        if taggedObject is not None:
            contentType = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(taggedObject)
            if contentType is not None:
                validated_data["content_type"] = contentType
                validated_data["object_id"] = taggedObject.id
        return super(FooSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
```